# How to pass multiple variables?

Tags: jquery, css, variables

I have a variable:

```
var options = {'transition-duration': dataspeed + 'ms',
'transition-timing-function': dataeasing, 
'transition-delay': datadelay + 'ms'};
```

Then I'm trying to use this variable in:

```
$(this).css({'opacity':'1'}, options);
```

The opacity works fine but the variable options are not passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use

```
 $(this).css({'opacity':'1'}).css(options);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I actually tried this solution right after I made the post. Should have played around a little more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also merge both objects:

```
$(this).css($.extend({'opacity':'1'}, options));
```